# Alamofire ObjectMapper, Int to enum is incorrect

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire with ObjectMapper. I need to convert an Int to the enum. Code like so:

```
enum CountryCode: Int {
    /**
     Hong Kong

     Raw value: 852
     */
    case HK = 852
    /**
     Singapore

     Raw value: 65
     */
    case SG = 65
    /**
     Taiwan

     Raw value: 886
     */
    case TW = 886
    /**
     China

     Raw value: 86
     */
    case CN = 86
}

func mapping(map: Map) {
        countryCode <- (
            map["country_code"],
            TransformOf<CountryCode, Int>(fromJSON: { (value: Int?) -> CountryCode in
                return CountryCode(rawValue: value ?? CountryCode.HK.rawValue)!
                }, toJSON: { (value: CountryCode?) -> Int? in
                    return value?.rawValue
            })

        )
}
```

The returned value defaults to HK every single time, no matter what the Int value is. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have to create a custom `TransformOf` instance at all? Since your country code has a default value you can assign it in field declaration as follow :

```
var countryCode : CountryCode =  CountryCode.HK
```

and then in mapping function use the default ObjectMapper's EnumTransform

```
countryCode <- (map["country_code"],EnumTransform<CountryCode>())
```

Comment: It uses this the mapping function in various places in the program where it may need to default to HK so setting the default to HK in the var declaration won't work.

Comment: How to return nil instead of creating whole object when enum not found for raw value?